# Why does ROS not have any GUI and support for Windows?

Tags: ros, windows, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS developers have developed a great platform for Robotics Programming indeed.

But why is it so hard to make a Graphical User Interface like many other softwares and built-in *Eclipse* like environment?

And since most of the world use Windows, it is very inconvenient to switch to Ubuntu to use ROS!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235452/why-does-ros-not-have-any-gui-and-support-for-windows?/) by [SarSam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26371/sarsam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2016-05-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-05-28**:
"And since most of the world use Windows" I'd love to have a robot that just shuts down from time to time to update or exchange it's OS :) Which problems do you have with a gui? QT is a good option for graphical Interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> But why is it so hard to make a
> Graphical User Interface like many
> other softwares and built-in Eclipse
> like environment?

If it is not so hard, then you should create one.

Inconvenienced Windows users would sing your praises; high praise indeed!

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2016-05-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An viable alternative for the Windows' classrooms enviroment (or for Microsoft Windows OS users) is to use a Ubuntu virtual machine over a Windows OS using Virtual Box. Even virtual machine with ROS installed ready-to-use exists as .ova files for VirtualBox from nootrix http://nootrix.com/software/virtualizing-ros/

---

Originally posted by [andruino](https://answers.ros.org/users/6070/andruino/) with karma: 31 on 2016-05-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From this week's ros-users mailing list:

- https://github.com/codenotes/ros_cygwin
- https://github.com/uml-robotics/ROS.NET

Personally, I'd go the VM route though. Probably using Vagrant + Virtual Box.

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-05-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SarSam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26371/sarsam/) on 2016-05-29**:
Thanks! +1